# How to execute code when no result selected using Anorm?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, anorm

This code works fine when there are records matching the `WHERE` clause:

```scala
val pinfo = SQL("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id={id}").on("id" -> "scala")
pinfo().map { row =>
  println("have something")// runs when selected
}
```

What is going to happen when nothing is selected?

I'd like to print the following when no records are selected from MySQL.

```scala
println("nothing is selected")//if no row comes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SQL(...)()` returns a `Stream[SqlRow]` and streams have the [`isEmpty`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) method:

```
val pinfo: Stream[SqlRow] = SQL("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id={id}").on("id" -> "scala")()
if(!pinfo.isEmpty) pinfo.map { row => println("have something") }
else println("nothing is selected")
```

Also from the REPL:

```
scala> 1 #:: 2 #:: empty
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> res0.isEmpty
res1: Boolean = false

scala> empty
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Nothing] = Stream()

scala> res2.isEmpty
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I am having the same problem when I use your solution it says `not found: type SqlRow`.Can you help

Comment: I'm sorry but this was long time ago, are you sure you have the right import in your file?

Comment: I have imported `anorm._`  with you solution and it dint work But now the problem is solved removed `Stream[SqlRow]` in variable declaration and it worked like a charm.Your answer really helped, upvoting you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also parse it as a `Option[T]`, and then handle the case there is no value within this optional result.

```
val i: Option[Int] = SQL"SELECT int FROM test".as(scalar[String].singleOpt)
```

Comment: can you describe with basic example

Comment: `val i: Option[Int] = SQL"SELECT int FROM test".as(scalar[String].singleOpt)` then you can fold on that option to handle the `None` case (see "handle scalar result in https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/test/scala/anorm/AnormSpec.scala ).